# Bad access when loading .xib file

Tags: swift

Im having bad access on this line `super.init(coder: aDecoder)`. I've tried many solutions i found online but it does not solves it. Im using Swift2.0

```
import UIKit

class JobsView: UIView {

    // Our custom view from the XIB file
    var view: UIView!

    func xibSetup() {
        view = loadViewFromNib()

        // use bounds not frame or it'll be offset
        view.frame = bounds

        // Make the view stretch with containing view
        view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight]
        // Adding custom subview on top of our view (over any custom drawing > see note below)
        addSubview(view)
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {

        let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "JobsView", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

        return view
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        // 1. setup any properties here

        // 2. call super.init(frame:)
        super.init(frame: frame)

        // 3. Setup view from .xib file
        xibSetup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        // 1. setup any properties here

        // 2. call super.init(coder:)
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        // 3. Setup view from .xib file
        xibSetup()
    }
}
```

Im calling this Nib from this method

```
func kolodaViewForCardAtIndex(koloda: KolodaView, index: UInt) -> UIView {
        //return UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Card_like_\(index + 1)"))
        return (NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("JobsView",owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? UIView)!

    }
```

Comment: Where does it crash exactly? Also does your nib have an owner?

Comment: I'm getting the same issue after updating Xcode yesterday. It happens for me on the super.init(coder: aDecoder) line. I'm also following the exact same tutorial as Exceptions for a UIDesignable view.